# What site would be more appropriate to ask a question about implementing the FastCGI protocol?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Currently I have a question and I don't know where to post the question. My question is about code, but about the "theoretical" part of the code. That is, to understand my question it is not necessary to add code, but the subject covers code. But mostly the question is theoretical and about how good an idea it is to do something. If you want more information about my question you can ask me and I will gladly give you more information. This is my question:

> ### How much do I really need the FCGI_END_REQUEST record in a FastCGI
> request?
>
> I am currently wanting to implement the FastCGI protocol in the Rust language. I'm implementing it without external libraries or something like that. But what I'm really looking for is to write code as close as possible to error-ready code but without unnecessary stuff. So, I already have all the code that makes complete requests to a file (in my specific case I make requests to a `.php` file using the `php-fpm` service). But then with that I can do what I really want (since my goal is to get the output and headers from a `.php` file). Now that I've explained my goal and what I'm looking for. do I really need to get the `FCGI_END_REQUEST` record? I mean, the [documentation](https://www.mit.edu/%7Eyandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html#S5.5) says that this record only brings information about the end of the request (or so I understand). But whether or not the request has errors would be reflected in `FCGI_STDOUT` or `FCGI_STDERR`, so I think I could just use `FCGI_STDOUT` and `FCGI_STDERR` to see possible errors. So how badly do I need to get the `FCGI_END_REQUEST` record? What are the advantages of implementing it? What advantages do I lose if I don't use it?

Comment: @RobertLongson Sure, let me add the question I would like to ask. And it's not so much that the code works or doesn't work, or a review, it's just to know how good an idea it is to do something.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/241919)

Comment: @RobertLongson I already added my question

Comment: @New1 what Robert is saying is that now that we've seen the question, it looks like it wouldn't fit *anywhere*, since the question is asking for an opinion and the sites here don't do opinions.

Comment: @Esther Oh well, I understand. So I delete this question?

Comment: Actually nevermind, it isn't really an opinion question (especially if you rephrase to focus on benefits and disadvantages). Maybe someone has a good recommendation for you

Comment: @Esther Well then I guess I'll wait...

Comment: You've accepted this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74074346/3648282 - is this question here still open, or is it resolved?